# Cannot open diagrams in SQL Server "SSMS 18 Has Stopped Working"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I'm going to open the Database Diagram in SQL Server, I could see this message box. Anyone can fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Just update your Management Studio to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of your SQL Server Management Studio version.  In `18.0` the database diagrams were deprecated and removed.

Then, in the next version, `18.1` the feature was added back. So, just install the latest version of the SQL S[ever Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) - currently `18.4`.

Comment: @Oshan What's your version?